# Can i get multiple data type records from sql to arraylist and get it in another form

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, winforms, arraylist

I'd like to get any of my tables record in arraylist and get it in another form (no matter how much columns for loop will retrieve data in to arraylist)
Here my code:

```
public static ArrayList getrecord(String Table, String Column, Int32 id)
{
    ArrayList asd = new ArrayList();
    Form1.con.Close();
    Form1.con.Open();
    SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand("Select * from " + Table + " where " + Column + " = " + id, Form1.con);
    SqlDataReader sdr = sq.ExecuteReader();
    if (sdr != null)
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            for(int i =0; i < sdr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                asd.Add(sdr.GetValue(i).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    return asd;
}
```

Comment: There is so much bad here. First is this is wide open to sql injection. This is not the right way to deal with queries at all. Secondly, you have a generic method to get a row from any table. This is data, not a generic. You have to use select * which means you will almost always be returning lots of data you don't actually need. The security and performance issues here are going to cause you lots of pain in the long run. I would consider completely rethinking how this works.

Comment: Than @SeanLange Sir can you please guide me a good way, actually i have created a class for all queries and calling every method in forms by clicking button. So what should i do? Should i query in button click function??

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You jumped from how you query data to where you call it. You should create procedures to retrieve data from your database. You call them in your code when you need the data. But for heaven's sake don't use this generic method of getting data.

Comment: @SeanLange please help me out i want to create stored procedure for this so can you give me code how can i create st_procedure with parameters for this query

Comment: i have created this procedure

Comment: How can I help you create a stored procedure? I have no idea what you want to do. And I am not going to show you how to do this with dynamic sql because that is the wrong way to handle data. It might be a good idea to take a class on this as it seems you need a lot of direction.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using DataTable instead of ArrayList. You can fill DataTable with all the records you need and use it in another form.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sq = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("your sql query", "your connection string");
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter sda = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sq);
sda.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: than in method which data type i have to use for getting data in another form

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{     
      string x = row["ColumnName"].ToString();
      int y = int.Parse(row["AnotherColumnName"].ToString());
}

Comment: its not passing row from one class to other form